# Delete duplicate records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query to select all the duplicated customers who have no orders :

```
select distinct * from [KUNDEN] k1
where not exists (
select * from [BELEG] b
where k1.Nummer = b.Adressnummer)
and exists (
select * from [KUNDEN] k2
where k1.Nummer <> k2.Nummer
and k1.Name = k2.Name
and k1.Vorname = k2.Vorname)
```

How can I change this query in order to delete these customers ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried swapping `select distinct *` with `delete` and see what you got?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353183/how-to-delete-all-duplicate-records-from-sql-table

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from [KUNDEN]
where nummer in (
    select distinct nummer
    from [KUNDEN] k1
    where not exists (
    select * from [BELEG] b
    where k1.Nummer = b.Adressnummer)
    and exists (
    select * from [KUNDEN] k2
    where k1.Nummer <> k2.Nummer
    and k1.Name = k2.Name
    and k1.Vorname = k2.Vorname)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have this error : `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'kunden' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: `delete from [KUNDEN]
where nummer in (
    select distinct nummer
    from (select * from [KUNDEN]) k1
    where not exists (
    select * from [BELEG] b
    where k1.Nummer = b.Adressnummer)
    and exists (
    select * from [KUNDEN] k2
    where k1.Nummer <> k2.Nummer
    and k1.Name = k2.Name
    and k1.Vorname = k2.Vorname)
)`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause