# Removing rows from table with specific distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this sample table

```
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
| ID | KeyAccountNumber | GList | StartDate  |  EndDate   |  Rate  |
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |              100 | ABCD  | 01-01-2015 | 01-30-2015 | 100.00 |
|  2 |              101 | ABECD | 02-01-2015 | 02-28-2015 | 105.00 |
|  3 |              100 | ABCD  | 01-01-2015 | 01-30-2015 | 107.00 |
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
```

What I need to accomplish, is for a given distinct 'KeyAccountNumber' and 'GList' value, I need to delete where the StartDate and EndDate are duplicated (remove both rows).

So in this case, I need to remove rows with ids 1 and 3, because they have the same KeyAccountNumber and the same GList value with the same dates in the StartDate and EndDate field, even thought the Rate field is different.

So, the output should look like this:

```
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
| ID | KeyAccountNumber | GList | StartDate  |  EndDate   |  Rate  |
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
|  2 |              101 | ABECD | 02-01-2015 | 02-28-2015 | 105.00 |
+----+------------------+-------+------------+------------+--------+
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer can be adapted to your needs:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6353499/1507566

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE t
FROM YourTable t
Group By KeyAccountNumber,GList,StartDate,EndDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```